# aws sqs messages marked as inflight without being received

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

I have a java application using JMS to read from a AWS SQS standard queue.  I am seeing some requests being marked as in-flight, but without being received.  I have stepped through the application with a debugger and some requests simply are not triggering the receive() function, but the AWS console shows the requests as in-flight.

Comment: Any chance that you have received a batch of SQS messages but your code incorrectly assumes that it's received only one message?

Comment: The API only returns one message (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive--).